# Copying selected features to existing feature class using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

Is there a way to copy a selected feature into an existing feature class?

Sort of like append would do, but only the selected features.

I want to iterate through a table and select features with a matching attribute in a feature class and copy that selected feature into an existing feature class.

Basically, it'd be like selected a feature in ArcMap and copying and pasting it into a different feature class.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a layer of selected features with [make feature layer tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000) and then use the [append tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000050000000).

"Map layers can be used as Input Datasets. If a layer has a selection, only the selected records (features or table rows) are used by the Append tool."

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use an input feature to update an existing feature this code will help do that. I you want to insert that will be another code entirely. Let me know if this is what you want

```
fc1 = "input_feature"
fc2 = "existing_feature"



with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, ["input_field","input_field"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        SQL_stat = "input_field = " +str(row[0])
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, ["input_field", "existing_field"], SQL_stat) as cursor1:
            for row1 in cursor1:
                row1[1] = row[1]
                cursor1.updateRow(row1)
print("Done")
```

Comment: Two problems: This would only work if `Layer` object exists with the name "input_feature" (since the requirement is to work on a selection set), and `UpdateCursor.updateRow()` doesn't do an INSERT operation, `InsertCursor` does. Append on a layer selection set (as in the accepted answer) would be way faster, as well.